# How can I use the css file from react-table in my react project along with css modules?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-table

I have been using css modules in my react project, and recently installed react-table using [THIS SITE](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme), but I'm having problem importing its css file. The source of react-table says I need to import the css file from react-modules like:

```
import "react-table/react-table.css";
```

but it doesn't work. I think it has something todo with using css modules, but I don't know how to fix it. I found [THIS THREAD](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/pull/65) about this issue, but couldn't understand if there really is a solution for it or not.

Comment: Could you include your webpack loaders in the question?

Comment: I'd appreciate if you tell me how to do that since I've never dealt with webpack loaders directly

Comment: What development environment are you using? create-react-app?

Comment: Yes I'm using create react app and I did "npm-run-eject" in the beginning to be able to use css modules.

Comment: Alright. [You can use css modules with CRA by naming your files `example.module.css`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/366e5d3475fa21fe4743c6865b870d9f0e2bbbcc/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L299-L308) without ejecting though.

Comment: Yes I could probably do that but I was following a tutorial when I started building this app, and it seems once the app is ejected, there is no way back. It is a project being worked on with some other people on github, so I can't create a new one

Comment: If you have ejected and `react-table/react-table.css` is being treated as css modules, you must look in your webpack configuration files and see how you changed them according to the tutorial. You might want to use a [resource query](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-resourcequery) so you can treat the file as regular css with e.g. `import "react-table/react-table.css?no-module";`

Answer (score 1):

import ReactTable from 'react-table-6'

import 'react-table-6/react-table.css'

This solved my problem. For Reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-6

Answer (score 0):

If you want full .js environment you can use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)

I really having zen using it by converting `react-table.css` to component. just wrap it like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ReactTableStyles = styled.div`
// react-table.css content
`;
export default ReactTableStyles;
```

Then in your ReactTable component, you just need to nest inside it as so:

```
   <ReactTableStyles>
      <ReactTable
        ... />
   </ReactTableStyles>
```

Hope it helps someone.